# Reboot Remote Shutdown server linux

Tags: linux, cluster, cloudera

I remotely manage a hadoop cluster by Cloudera manager. I accidentally shutdown one of the servers and need to reboot it. I have tried ssh but I cannot connect to host. Is there another way for me to reboot the server without physically being there?

Answer (score 0):

If the server has a remote management system like ILO (HP) iDraq (Dell) etc than you can use that to power-on/reboot and other tasks.

If you are in the same LAN you can use WOL (Wake On Lan) but this needs to be enabled on the bios .